# Problem with PyGame - libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: drivers, intel, mesa

I am approaching **pygame** now, I am running a small program that opens a pygame window and shows an intro, which is a simple screen with a background and two buttons (they light up only when the mouse is hovered over).

When I run the code I am shown the following terminal error:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-driubr42/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /usr/lib/dri/crocus_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: crocus
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  105
  Current serial number in output stream:  106
```

From how I read it looks like a video driver problem, I have the **Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)** , and my **Ubuntu version is 21.10** . My laptop is **DELL LATITUDE E6440** with **Intel® Core™ i5-4300M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4** .

Someone can help me??

Comment: Try running `suso apt update && sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri` or try running your script with `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965 script.py`

Answer (score 0):

I use miniconda on manjaro amd64 without video card. In conda env py3.7 it got this error. I turn off env use system to play pygame. And it work out fine